# Flutter: how to keep widget with Google Map unchanged?

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I am using [Google Maps for Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) widget.
In my app map is displayed via one of the tabs of BottomNavigationBar.

And I have the following problem:

1. user is on Map's tab
2. user changes tab (by tapping on another one)
3. [PROBLEM] when user returns on Map's tab map redraws.

I would like to keep map as it is when user leaves Map's tab, so he can continue to work with it when he returns to it later on.

Tried to:

- use PageStorage - without success.
- make something like Singletone of Map's state - without success.
- use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin ([saw here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439047/how-to-preserve-widget-states-in-flutter-when-navigating-using-bottomnavigation)), which looked promising, but still without success.

(I admit that I could have done something wrong)

Code of last attempt:

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MapScreenState();
}

class MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Map"),
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        )
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
      mapController = controller;
      updateKeepAlive();
  }
}
```

So, I just need a way to either keep MapScreen alive and unchanged, or to store its state somehow and restore it when user returns to MapScreen. Or something else which will solve the problem.

Comment: Couple of extra thoughts to Diegos answer. You could use an Offstage widget, and move the widget offscreen and back when navigating. I don't know google_maps plugin, but can you store the camera position separately and include that in the google_maps widget as an example workaround, if that is what is getting reset each time and causing the problem.

Comment: @Ian Tried Offstage widget, still same behavior. Problem is not only camera position, but also time which map takes to load. I'll probably store camera position (and other options if needed) for now, but if I find or come up with a solution I will post it here.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Google Maps widget is in a developer preview state at version 0.2. Some behavior may change over time. Do not use this in production yet.

Comment: Did you already find a solution? I'm facing this problem aswell.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @AQRC

Comment: @TheTokenizer I quite stopped work on my flutter project, so the answer is no, unfortunately I didn't find solution

Answer (score 8):

Use [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html)

For example:

```
Class _ExamplePageState extends State<ExamplePage> {
  int _bottomNavIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    WidgetOne(),
    WidgetTwo(),
    GoogleMap(),
  ]

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _bottomNavIndex,
        children: _children,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          if (_bottomNavIndex == index) return;
          setState(() {
            _bottomNavIndex = index;
          });
        }
        items: [ ... ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Widget` always rebuild after you change from page to page, so, try this , use a variable for `GoogleMap` and reuse if it's different from null.

```
    GoogleMap _map;

     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if (_map == null){
        _map =  GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          );
      }
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Map"),
          ),
          body:_map,
      );
    }
```

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately widget not only "rebuilds", but does it by "recreating its state" by calling `createState()` when page is changed back and forth, so `_map` will always be `null` on `build` method call. Also tryed the same approach with `createState()` (create state if it is null, otherwise return state created earlier), but it causes assertion errors in the framework.

Comment: are you using  AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin ?

Comment: Yes, I am. Even made State<GoogleMap> to use it, but it doesn't help. For now I am going to store camera position and all other data, as Ian suggested. If I find or come up with a solution I will post it here though

Comment: How did you fixed this?

Comment: AQRC, have you found a solution?

Comment: @AQRC Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Same problem here - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I was just having this same problem and the mixin solved it. I think you've just missed enter the type of mixin at the end of its declaration.

```
class MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MapScreenState>
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45944777/losing-widget-state-when-switching-pages-in-a-flutter-pageview) thread if anything.

Comment: This did not work for me, is there anything else you've needed to do? what's your setup?

Answer (score 0):

```
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
```

To

```
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MapScreenState>
```