# Flutter GoogleMap in a PageView build only ONCE

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I have a **PageView**.builder and 3 **GoogleMap**-s in it.

I had to create the 3 widgets only the first time, and I do not want to rebuild them again. 
Now it is annoying when I just change the page it is flashing once before load. And slow.

Any way to build a FIXED state on that widget?

I tried:

**AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin**

and

**@override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;**

but not worked.

Comment: Please share your code to get any help!

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43785 it looks like something broken in the google_maps.dart

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe you forget to call `super.build(context);` in build method.

Like this:

```
class TestInnerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestInnerPageState createState() => _TestInnerPageState();
}

class _TestInnerPageState extends State<TestInnerPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Dont't forget this
    super.build(context);

    return Container();
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: The method 'build' is always abstract in the supertype., when i call super.build(context)

Comment: @AparAmin When you add the mixin `with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to the state class then you can call the `super.build(context);`

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted answer, this will be an example using google maps.

```
class TestInnerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestInnerPageState createState() => _TestInnerPageState();
}

class _TestInnerPageState extends State<TestInnerPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  //Variables
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  void onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Dont't forget this
    super.build(context);

    return GoogleMap(
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      compassEnabled: false,
      myLocationEnabled: false,
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      // compassEnabled: true,
      tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
      // markers: _markers,
      // polylines: _polylines,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
        bearing: CAMERA_BEARING,
        tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
        target: LatLng(
            //SOURCE_LOCATION
            7.8731,
            80.7718),
      ),
      onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue working with google map in pageview but after searching online I got a solution that finally worked

All I did was put the google map in a stateful widget, used the `with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and  `@override bool get wantKeepAlive => true;` and called in the required widget
This is the stateful widget containing the google map

```
class GoogleMapWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  const GoogleMapWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GoogleMapWidgetState createState() => _GoogleMapWidgetState();
}

class _GoogleMapWidgetState extends State<GoogleMapWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child:GoogleMap(initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target:LatLng(0, 0)),)
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can call it from your Homepage like so

```
class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  build(BuildContext context){
      return PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
              GoogleMapWidget(),
              GoogleMapWidget(),

          ],
      );
   }
}
```

I hope this is the answer you're looking for