# Using Google Maps with PageView

Tags: flutter, google-maps, future, flutter-pageview

I am attempting to have a map render out as the first page/slide within a PageView which works perfectly fine, and I can even scroll/slide to the second page but when I attempt to return to the map I get an error stating the Future has already executed

```
PageView(
            controller: pageController,
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                buildingsEnabled: false,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
                myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(widget.task.locationCoords.latitude,
                      widget.task.locationCoords.longitude),
                  zoom: 15,
                ),
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
                // markers: {
                //   Marker(
                //     // icon: customIcon,
                //     markerId: MarkerId(widget.task.id),
                //     position: LatLng(widget.task.locationCoords.latitude,
                //         widget.task.locationCoords.longitude),
                //     infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                //       title: widget.task.title,
                //       snippet: widget.task.title,
                //     ),
                //   )
                // },
                circles: {
                  Circle(
                      circleId: const CircleId('taskArea'),
                      center: LatLng(widget.task.locationCoords.latitude,
                          widget.task.locationCoords.longitude),
                      radius: 250,
                      fillColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
                      strokeColor: Colors.blue.shade100),
                },
              ),
              Image.network(
                  'https://www.saturdayeveningpost.com/wp-content/uploads/satevepost/mowing_sl.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)
            ],
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              setState(() {
                currentPage = page + 1;
              });
            },
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          )),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the map in StatefulWidget and use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487159/5034477)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33701574)